# Does setRetainInstance() method retain ArrayAdapter data?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working in an application that has a `SearchActivity`; the search activity is only a container for the "SearchFragment" and "SearchFragment" contains a `SearchView` in the ActionBar, and its main layout has a `RecyclerView` to display search results. Supposing that the user perform a search, the results are showed within `RecyclerView` and then user rotate the screen...Thinking in that case i use the `setRetainInstance(true)` method. I assumed that my custom ArrayAdapter data will saved, but it was not. I know that i can save ArrayAdapter data in a `Bundle` for `onSaveInstanceState()` method. But i want to know why `setRetainInstance()` method does not work.

```java
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment
                implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
                ResultsListAdapter.ItemClickListener {

            private ResultsListAdapter mListAdapter;
            private CustomRecyclerView resultsList;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                mListAdapter = new ResultsListAdapter(new ArrayList<Kiosk>(), this);

                resultsList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
                resultsList.setLayoutManager(linearManager);
                resultsList.setSetEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view));

                if (savedInstanceState == null){
                    setRetainInstance(true);
                }

                return rootView;
            }
         @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                if(s.isEmpty()) {
                    //Set an empty array, to set an empty view
                    mListAdapter.changeData(new ArrayList<Kiosk>());
                    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                ArrayList<Kiosk> kiosksFound = performSearch(s);

                mListAdapter.changeData(kiosksFound);
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if(s.isEmpty()) {
                    //Set an empty array, to set an empty view
                    mListAdapter.changeData(new ArrayList<Kiosk>());
                    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }

                ArrayList<Kiosk> kiosksFound = performSearch(s);

                mListAdapter.changeData(kiosksFound);
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }

  }
```

Comment: I wonder if calling the method earlier in the `Fragment`'s lifecycle has an impact. Have you tried calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel, yes i tried but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you retain the state, `onCreateView` will still be called. Since you recreate the list view there, the data is cleared.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!. I initialize the adapter in `onCreate()` method, instead `onCreateView()`. That way the data is not cleared.

Comment: @Silmood this is not a good approach, since the adapter holds a reference to the view, in fact, you should call `adapter = null` inside `onDestroyView()` to avoid leaks. I suggest to keep your data in a field of the fragment class, and add it to the adapter after recreating it inside `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't keep you data inside the views, like activity, fragment, or adapter, if you separate view and model, then you will not worry about data loss, when views are destroying, it is also good when your model has multiple representation in the different views, for example show it as a list view or grid view.
[Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)